# Why is port not open? (Not UFW; Service is running)

Tags: networking, server, firewall, connection, ufw

On the target machine, running Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :2113
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2113   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      24854/eventstored
```

The service responds to HTTP request:

```
$ curl localhost:2113
Moved
```

Tried with UFW disabled, and enabled with port 2113 open:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Or:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2113                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2113 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

In both cases, from the client machine (also running Ubuntu 18.04)

```
$ curl 192.168.178.34:2113
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.178.34 port 2113: Connection refused
```

Ping confirms the IP address is correct.

What else may be preventing the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only listens on the loopback interface 127.0.0.1:

```
$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :2113
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2113   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      24854/eventstored
```

Services will only receive packets from interfaces they listen to. You can commonly specify 0.0.0.0 as listen address in the service, to make it listen on *all* interfaces.

According to the [documentation, port 2113 is the administrative interface](https://eventstore.org/docs/getting-started/index.html). It may be a good idea to leave this accessible only to localhost, and use [ssh port forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237904/what-does-port-forwarding-mean-in-ssh-port-forwarding) to access the service.